# Form not passing POST data

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, send

I've been having this problem for a while, this is the code for my form:

```
    <form action="site/Main.php" method="post">
        <p><label for="user" style="text-indent:415px;">User</label> <input type="text" name="user" /></p>
        <p><label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="log in" /></p>
    </form>
```

this form is at my admin.php page and I want to pass the variables "user" and "password" to my site/main.php page, however, when I try to access the variables php tells me it they do not exist, this is the code I have on my site/main.php page:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
        if($_POST["user"] == "Project" && $_POST["password"] == "Project2012"){
            echo "Welcome!";
        } else{
            echo "Wrong username or password!";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And I keep getting the following error:

(!) Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\site\Main.php on line 10

Any idea of why it seems that the $_POST variables are not being sent to my Main page?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: First of all - var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Second of all, don't just blindly access array elements. `if(isset($_POST['user'])` *then* `if($_POST['user'] == 'Project')`.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but note that `isset($_POST)` is always `true`. If nothing was posted, $_POST is an empty array, but it's still there.  However, empty arrays evaluate to `false`, so `if($_POST)` would do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @octern: better yet, `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`. why mess around with checking for vars/values that may or may not be there, when you can do this and be 100% accurate, every single time.

Comment: @MarcB You're right, as a matter of policy it's better to test for what you're testing for, rather than testing for something that happens to be the same thing due to a quirk of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very strange, but after a few tries, what I did was change:

```
    <form action="site/Main.php" method="post">
```

for:

```
    <form action="Main.php" method="post">
```

And it started working, then I changed it back to its original form and it kept working. Thanks everyone for your comments, they all helped me with different ways on checking on my variables, thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the $_POST array with empty() not isset().  Also, always check a index of array before trying to compare or use.

```
<?php
   if(!empty($_POST)){
     if(isset($_POST["user"])  && 
       isset($_POST["password"]) && 
       $_POST["user"] == "Project" && 
       $_POST["password"] == "Project2012"){
         echo "Welcome!";
     } else{
         echo "Wrong username or password!";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: This looks like a more meticulous way to do it, but I don't think it answers the question: Why are one or both of the variables missing from $_POST right after the form is posted?

Answer (score 0):

Is

> C:\wamp\www\site\Main.php

actually the right folder/file?
As other users mentioned, you should use

```
if(isset($_POST['user']))
```

but still, you're using site/Main.php in your form as the path. The error message you posted tells us that the $_POST data is being sent to `C:\wamp\www\site\Main.php` - Is that where your file is? If not, that's the error.

Best Regards,

Stephan S.

**Edit:** As mentioned, this can't actually be the error. I'd suggest to just `var_dump($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST);` in your Main.php

**And**: Is that actually your code? I mean in your code example there doesn't even exist a line 10 in your Main.php

Comment: HTML forms always direct you to the page to which the data was posted, right? So even if the OP is confused about which page they're going to, the page they end up on should have access to the posted data.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My bad. But since it's mentioning line 10(the script) there's something wrong about the code he posted. Because there is no line 10.

Comment: I already solved it, I will post it as an answer once the site allows me to. Thanks to all for your help!